# Proving Algebraic Multiplicity doesn't equal Geometric Multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, diagonalization, matrix-rank

I'm trying to show that the upper triangular matrix below is not diagonalisable.

Note, each $\star$ can represent any complex number.

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 100 & \star & \dots & \star \\
    0 & 1 & \star & \dots & \star\\
    0 & 0 &  201 & \dots & \star \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \star\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & \star \\
    \end{bmatrix}$

I know that the algebraic multiplicity of $1$ is at least $2$ and hope to prove that the geometric multiplicity of $1$ is less than or equal to $1$.

I've tried using rank-nullity theorem to prove this, but have had no success.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the other diagonal elements can be arbitrary then the geometric multiplicity could be $>1$.  But then the algebraic multiplicity would be $>2$, so it’s not so much that the claim is false as the approach you are using contains this flaw.

Answer (score 2):

Let $e_1, \dotsc, e_n$ be the standard basis and $U=\langle e_1, e_2 \rangle$.

If $A$ were diagonalisable, then so were $A_{|U}=\begin{pmatrix}1&100\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you please explain why A being diagonalisable implies $A_{|U}=\begin{pmatrix}1&100\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ is diagonalisable?

Comment: The restriction of a diagonalisalbe endomorphism to an invariant subspace is again diagonalisable. You will find this in any book on linear algebra.